# Handle Unicode Words in Regex Parsing

Tags: java, android, regex, string, unicode

I am trying to get all words before a specific word in one Indian language (Bengali). The technique works perfect for English but fails for Bengali:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([\\w\\s]+) ছবি", Pattern.UNICODE_CASE);
Matcher m = p.matcher("ক্যামেরাকে ছবি তোলা এবং ভিডিও রেকর্ড এর অনুমতি দেবেন");

while (m.find()) {
      System.err.println(m.group(1));
}
```

So Ideally, I am trying to get the word `ক্যামেরাকে` as an output, which is before the text `ছবি তোলা এবং ভিডিও রেকর্ড...`. Now incidentally this is the first word in this example, but it may not be the case.

How can I do it? Well I am trying to do this on Android.

EDIT

Trying the Java solution leads here:

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: What error you got ?

Comment: @AmirHKH I didn't get an output at all!

Comment: Try `\p{InBeng}`, `Pattern.compile("([\\p{InBeng}\\s]+) ছবি")`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew No luck! Same error!

Comment: Something is just wrong, no idea what. What about `\p{L}`  / `\pL` / `\p{IsL}`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I think this has to do with JDK 6 and 7. i am trying that now! It seems these flags are supported only by JDK 7

Comment: You should have mentioned these details in the question.

Comment: BTW, `\p{L}` is already present in Java 6.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I just found this out a few minutes back! It seems I was researching in the wrong area!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this for Bengali letters:

```
Pattern.compile("([\\p{IsBeng}\\s]+) ছবি", Pattern.UNICODE_CASE);
```

`\p{xxx}` can be used for a lot of character classes, such as categories, but also for scripts, where you need to know the name and prefix with `Is`.

It is also possible to use

```
Pattern.compile("([\\w\\s]+) ছবি", Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS);
```

but this will match letters from *any* alphabet, so I'm not sure what you really need.

Comment: I tried using your first solution in Android, failed, it showed unknown charecter category for isbeng. trying second one now!

Comment: @Jeet.Deir It seems that `\w` is Unicode aware by default in Android. `Pattern.compile("([\\w\\s]+) ছবি")` should work as is.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I thought the same. It doesn;t work for Android

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I updated the question with some details! Also, Andoird doesn't accept the `Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS` flag as it is enabled by deafult. :(

Comment: Anybody looking for an answer, the correct tag is `InBENGALI`